# Find the 6-digit number encoded in this "mathematical" diagram

Tags: logical-deduction, password

In the diagram below you can see four independent patterns. Each pattern is a puzzle by itself, and by solving it you will be able to encounter one or more digits of the final, 6-digit numeric solution. Signs above tell how to get these digits once the mini-puzzle is solved.

Most puzzlers should already be familiarized with the challenge presented by these patterns. However, the solution is this case involves numbers as well as letters.

**Backstory:** *"The 6-digit number you will find is a password that allows you to enter the fifth dimension and therefore become one with the universe. Also, it's the only way to save humanity."*

[image]

Contrary to what my storytelling skills may indicate, no black sorcery is required in the solution to this puzzle.

**Also, please notice that this post contains hidden tag(s), which would otherwise hurt the purpose of the puzzle.**

Hint:

> It's natural for you to be *clueless* during these puzzles. However, numbers may come in handy when words are lacking.

Comment: The "sum pi sum pi" at the top is just making me hungry.

Comment: This seems rather broad.  There are many ways to get numbers out of the patterns.

Comment: Just to be clear on the rules.  You're saying that there are 1 or more digits associated with each diagram, and you either add or multiply those digits to get a number.  You then concatenate the four numbers to get a six digit number.

Comment: Each subpuzzle is like a game. The solutions are converted into digits, and digits concatenated into the password

Comment: The symbols indicate how the digits are obtained from the solutions

Comment: That last edit was clearly very important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each puzzle is a

> crossword

to be solved by

> filling in written-out English numbers of the correct length

Solving its gives

> `TEN      TEN`
>    `I      W I     O   O O`
>    `N   ZERO N   TEN   NINE`
>    `E        E     E   E E`

We interpret each of these by computing the corresponding:

> sum of 19, product of 0, sum of 11, product of 9

and concatenating gives the six-digit answer

> 190119

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give this a shot:

Each bend in the string of dots represents a new number to be summed ($\Sigma$) or product-ed ($\Pi$).

We go in order:

1. 3 + 4 = 7
2. 4 × 3 × 3 × 4 = 144
3. 3 + 3 = 6
4. 4 × 3 × 3 = 36

But 7144636 is *seven* digits, so this is obviously not the right answer. Am I on the right track, though?

Comment: Another possible answer with a different algorithm that's actually 6 digits: 630516

Comment: It should be more like a game, not a code. Each mini-puzzle should be in some way "solvable", like finding an answer that fits the constraints.